# Does the size of primitiveData types used change during serializing object using LongWritable in java?

Tags: java

What is the size in memory of the `Edge` object created here?

```
public class Edge<E extends Writable, I extends Writable, J extends Writable> implements IEdge<E, I, J> {
    private Writable _source;
    private E _value;
    private J edgeID;
    private I _sink;

    public Edge(J id, I sinkID) {
        edgeID = id;
        _sink = sinkID;
    }

    public Edge(Writable sourceID, J id, I sinkID) {
        this(id,sinkID);
        _source = sourceID;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does the size of primitiveData types used change

No.

> during serializing object using LongWritable in java?

Irrelevant.

Comment: Does it add some header during serialize the object??

Comment: Try and you'll see.